# Extra character in PHP's exec() output on Windows 7 CLI

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface, composer-php

Without any apparent reason, I can't update my Composer-managed dependencies anymore. After some investigation, it turns out that PHP prepends an extra character to any use of its `exec` method.

Basic example :

```
php -r "var_dump(exec('echo lol', $output, $exit), $output, $exit);"
```

Gives out :

```
string(4) "♀lol"
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "♀lol"
}
int(0)
```

That `♀` character actually is an `FF` (formfeed) character (0x0C).

My Googling took me here:

- [Composer won't update dependencies due to random formfeed char (0x0c) - Composer Issue #1374](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1373)

But it appears that my problem differs from the one in this topic, as in it, the dreaded character appears with `shell_exec` and not `exec`. In my case it does appear with `exec`.

Any thoughts about this ? I wondered whether I should post here or at SuperUser, feel free to move this question if it doesn't belong here.

**EDIT :** BTW, I'm on Windows 7 64 bits, using Wamp with PHP 5.4.12 :)

**EDIT 2 :** Output for `php-v` :

```
PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2013 00:29:22) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Output for `php --ini` :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: The `php -r` example you give does not align with the example output you give. Most likely both are totally unrelated and this has nothing to do with PHP CLI executing the exec command. Also double check you don't have any auto-prepend script or similar. Also WAMP is known to do akward things with the PHP CLI binary, so double check which binary you actually execute there which can be also important for the ini-configuration used.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed I pasted the wrong output and edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Is that a fake edit or is that the *real* output from your cmd? And what does `php -nr "var_dump(exec('echo lol', $output, $exit), $output, $exit);"` give?

Comment: That's the real thing, except I replace FF characters with "♀" as this is what I see in the console. The true character appears if I redirect the command's output into a text file. / Edit : same result with php -nr

Comment: Also please add the output of `php -v` and `php --ini` to your question.

Comment: So you see `FF` in the cmd window?

Comment: Added what you requested. In the cmd window I don't see `FF`, I see `♀` instead. `FF` is only visible as itself in text files where I redirect the output of these commands in, and it's not visible at all when I copy-paste these into StackOverflow for example (but it's still here, I can see I have an extra character when using backspace or del keys).

Comment: I just tried downloading PHP 5.5.3 binaries for Windows. When running the same command in cmd (C:\php-5.3.3\php -r "..."), I get the same output (with the unwanted character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my apologies, I'm stupid. I had the answer right in front of me the whole time.

I re-read more carefully the issue on Composer's GitHub I linked to (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1373). In it, the person encountering the issue says he fixed it by removing the call to `cls` in a .bat file he got executed at shell start by calling it in Windows's registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`).

I actually had a .bat file called here on an unrelated matter, which contained a call to `cls`. So my Windows and PHP are fine - I just set up somthing aside that caused the trouble, which I did not realize until now.

Still good to know that this type of stuff can mess with PHP accessing the shell... Thank you anyway @hakre for your time.